# create maven junit test library for a module

Tags: java, maven, junit

Consider a maven utility module (module 1) that defines an abstract class: 
AbstractFoo.java. Under the test resources, a mockup of said class is written: FooMockup.java. Also a test class is written: AbstractFooTest.java.

Now consider a second module (module 2) that contains a class that uses an AbstractFoo, and also declares test cases: Bar.java and BarTest.java. BarTest.java creates an instance of FooMockup while creating an instance of Bar.

Dependencies are straightforward.

Module 1 src:  depends on nothing

Module 1 test: depends on module 1 src

Module 2 src:  depends on module 1 src

Module 2 test: depends on module 1 and 2 src and module 1 test

There is no circular dependency here. The problem arises when using maven. Maven provides two ways of importing test dependencies: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

If I use the "easy way", then maven refuses to manage transitive dependencies, which is neither easy nor preferred. To use the "preferred way", I have to move tests for module 1 into its own module. Because the mockup depends on module 1 src, and module 1 test depends on the mockup, I have to keep the mockup in the same package as the mockup. The maven standard is to keep tests under src/test, not in a separate module. Consequently, this breach in maven standard doesn't integrate well with some IDEs, and requires configuration in others.

Other than creating a custom maven plugin that resolves transitive test dependencies for a test scoped jars, is there a means to keep AbstractFooTest in the same module as AbstractFoo AND have maven resolve transitive dependencies for FooMockup?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use your test objects in another project. Alternatively, use something like Mockito to quickly create your mock objects.

Comment: @TedTrippin Thanks. I'm aware of that library. I gave the example I did for brevity and simplicity. In real life, I'm not actually using a mockup but a utility class. If this simple case can be solved, I can extend the solution to my actual problem. I prefer to be taught to fish, not given one. :)

Comment: Are those tests unit tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise We're using standard junit to build both unit tests and integration tests (maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin).

Comment: Unit tests are located within the same module. Integration tests can be in a separate module...If you like to create test packages only make a usual module put your base classes etc. into `src/main/java` and use the only in scope test...simplest solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Refer [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1378). More specifically,

> The problem here is that by design test dependencies are not transitive

We face similar problem and created test-infrastructure project which keeps classes in src/main. In the long run, this proved useful as it lead to better segregation of projects.

If you want to stick to your current way, then you just have to duplicate dependencies or keep it in parent pom.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of.